# Is there a way to use a plugin/macro in Confluence to display results on a page?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Completely hypothetical here, was just wondering if anyone had any thoughts.

I've created a REST endpoint in Confluence which uses the REST API Browser.

I've had an idea that involves displaying results from the REST endpoint on a specific Confluence page in a table form. Does anyone know if this would be possible?

So a user goes into a Confluence page to edit it and either uses a macro or plugin to access the REST endpoint. REST then returns the information the user requires and the user can display this information on the page.

I was thinking it would have to involve either:

1. Writing a Macro which accesses the REST endpoint itself and converts the results into a table.
2. Writing a Macro which accesses the REST API Browser to get results and then display that in a table.

I'm not expecting any in-depth answers here, I'm just wondering if anyone has tried anything similar? Or has any thoughts as to how I could begin to go about this? My searches haven't brought back any similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Confluence Server, I would start by forking a very simple Confluence add-on, e.g. [Gister](https://bitbucket.org/dvdsmpsn/gister-github-gist-macro-for-confluence-server).

In the [execute method](https://bitbucket.org/dvdsmpsn/gister-github-gist-macro-for-confluence-server/src/1c52a5df2d223cb574db043a6be14b03028f2ca9/src/main/java/me/davidsimpson/confluence/addon/gister/GistMacro.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), of the macro, I'd swap out the code which is there and replace it with something more like this:

```
@Override
public String execute(Map<String, String> parameters,
                      String body,
                      ConversionContext conversionContext)
        throws MacroExecutionException {
    String url = parameters.get("url");        
    return "<script>/*your code here*/</script><div data=rest-url='"" + url + "\" class=\"macro-rest-api\"></div>";
}
```

This will get you started allowing you to inject the correct REST API into the page.

Later you'll likely need to add some more parameters so that it's a bit more dynamic.

You can then write your own JavaScript in this section `/*your code here*/` which prints a table in the nearest `dicv.macro-rest-api`

Also, look to move your JavaScript into a separate [web-resource module](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/web-resource-module) so that you can update it w/o recompiling.